# "Hacker" utility: space-efficient embedding a file into JPEG file container

Tags: images, image-processing, data

With the advent of social media platforms and **pervasive free image hosting** (for example, Amazon's [recent "unlimited photo storage" for Prime members](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/unlimited)), **I would like to take advantage of this to (surreptitiously?) store other types of data**. Cursory web searches don't turn up much of anything.

I'm not interested in steganography, per se. Tools like [steghide](http://steghide.sourceforge.net) will embed data into JPEG images, sure -- but with ***very*** limited storage space inside of a container image.

What I want is a more space-efficient re-encapsulation of raw data into a JPEG file. The resulting image can (and should) look like ***garbage*** when rendered in a HTML page. That's fine with me. Obviously, this program should be free-ware/open-source. Additionally, this program should not store payloads within EXIF because such data are often stripped from images hosted on websites.

Ultimately, a browser plugin that could detect the presence of data "packaged" inside of images would be pretty cool.

Before I go out of my way to research and write such software, I want to know: **does this tool already exist?** Surely someone has already written something like this.

Comment: Raw idea: QR codes would match your description, maybe checking in that direction?

Comment: If you don't care that the image looks like garbage, then we can just take a JPEG, leave the headers in place & replace all JPEG data with your data? Simple enough, if you can code ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure.  If not, which operating system? Does it have to be free, or do you have a budget?

Comment: Beware of breaking terms of service & having your data deleted.

Comment: Btw, Jpeg has a limit of 4Gb or so ....

Comment: @Izzy: QR codes aren't as space-efficient as I am hoping for. Also, they are better suited for formats that handle 2 bit per pixel colorspaces, such as GIF or PNG.

Comment: OK, was just an idea. You may not like the other either: use small images and huge EXIF data :) // But we're getting OT, "how to X" doesn't fit here.

Comment: @Mawg : But, these images are beautiful impressionistic artwork! Yes, 4gb limit is fine. [RAR and ZIP file formats](http://acritum.com/winrar) handle this problem by **spanning**. Limits and what you describe can be handled via higher-level software control. I agree that using JPEG syntax and structure is the way to go. What I want to know if someone has already _done_ this before I go out of my way to write a new implementation.

Comment: @Izzy: Note that many online services strip EXIF data. Good thoughts. Slightly OT, but it is useful to narrow the scope of the question.

Comment: Yup, but we are not talking of stripping the EXIF, but rather the entire Jpeg **picture** data. Should be fairly trivial to code, but I don't know of anything that does what the OP wants off the shelf :-(

Comment: This will draw unwanted attention to you - paedophiles, "terrorists" and other undesirables do this.

Comment: @user3791372, I appreciate your perspective; [I'm certain that you're right](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans+3). I am interested in your motivations as to why you would mention this here.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not a solution for JPEG containers, this illustrates a solution that will work with **free Amazon Prime photo storage using a BMP container**.

"Japanese user YDKK has developed a tool to store arbitrary data inside a .bmp file, which can then be uploaded to Amazon's service. A 1.44GB test image containing an executable file uploaded at over 250Mb/sec, far faster than typical cloud storage services that are rate limited and don't allow extremely large files."

http://ydkk.hateblo.jp/entry/2016/01/25/115224